# Find a specific argument in Prolog predicate

Tags: prolog

If I have a predicate like that

```
some_predicate('12','Jon Doe', 'Unknown town').
```

Is it possible to get for example the 3rd arguments ? I'm thinking of a rule that could be written like that `nth_arg(+Predicate,+Nth,-Argument)`.

Does that kind of rule exists ?

Comment: What will you give to `+Predicate`? `some_predicate` or `some_predicate(12,'John Doe','Unknown town')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an ISO predicate, `arg/3`, that does exactly that:

```
?- arg(2, foo(a,b,c), Arg).

Arg = b

yes
| ?-
```

The proper terminology for the second argument is a *compound term* (a term with arguments). A *predicate* is a particular term, of the form `':-'(head, body)` or just a head, that defines a *rule*. Not all terms define rules. Sometimes they're just data structures.

You can, for example, get the entire body of a predicate as follows:

```
?- arg(2, (foo(X,Y) :- X > 1, Y is X * 3), Body).
Body = (X>1,Y is X*3)

yes
| ?-
```

This is because the given predicate is the term: `:-(foo(X,Y), (X > 1, Y is X*3))`.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot !